# Why did my color film overdevelop? Please help!

Tags: developing

I'm brand new to the home-developing game. I purchased the unicolor c41 developing kit and have developed 3 rolls of color film successfully so far. However, tonight I developed a roll of Kodak 400 color film and it came out very dark. I can barely make out images on the negatives (and can't read the film info on the margins). I'm assuming this means it overdeveloped; however I don't know why. I followed all procedural instructions and my temps were right on - 102 for dev and 98 for blix.

Please help!

Comment: Did you remember to set the ASA setting on your camera to 400

Comment: @Alaskaman Overexposing when shooting in the camera should not cause the margins to also be too dark.

Comment: Yeah, the camera was set to 400.

Comment: @MichaelC  Doh, i knew that. Did not read slowly enough.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the film was exposed to light i.e. fogged.

Comment: I was afraid this happened too, I just don't know when. The film was given to me from a friend, so maybe it happened w him and he didnt know it